# Firebase auth check for email already exists without using signInWithEmailAndPassword

Tags: firebase-authentication

I would like to check that if a email already exists in firebase auth server then ask for password from user.

There is a well known solution which is to use signInWithEmailAndPassword method and depend on the error message.  But in this case if the email does not exists it will create an account. I don't want to create an account I only want to know if the email already exists or not.

Should I use a a cloud function for this purpose ? How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`fetchSignInMethodsForEmail`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth.html#fetchsigninmethodsforemail). Here is an example with JavaScript:

```
firebase.auth().fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(email)
  .then((signInMethods) => {
    if (signInMethods.length) {
      // The email already exists in the Auth database. You can check the
      // sign-in methods associated with it by checking signInMethods array.
      // Show the option to sign in with that sign-in method.
    } else {
      // User does not exist. Ask user to sign up.
    }
  })
  .catch((error) => { 
    // Some error occurred.
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of **signInWithEmailAndPassword**, you can use **fetchSignInMethodsForEmail**. If you're using the new modular version in node can use it like this to check if an email is already registered.

```
import {  fetchSignInMethodsForEmail } from 'firebase/auth';

    fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(auth, email).then((result) => {
      console.log(result);
    });
```

It returns length of 0 if email doesn't exist, if the email does exist and is registered with email and password it will return length of 1 with value of 'password'.