# Verify if email is already in use from Firebase in HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to verify an email on Google Firebase without adding credentials to the database.
For example, I want it to acknowledge if an email is typed in the database will say the email cannot be used because it is already in use or is incorrect format. Also, I want it to verify that the password is valid for firebases '6' character passwords. I **do not** want to add any credentials to the database, only verify that the needs are being met

```
  signUp.addEventListener('click', (e) => {

//check if email and password valid first
//then display verification message


    var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var password = document.getElementById('password').value;


            createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
            .then((userCredential) => {




              // Signed in 
              // redirect to another page HERE!
              const user = userCredential.user;
              alert('Credentials are eligible! Complete your account!')
              // ...
            })
            
            .catch((error) => {
              const errorCode = error.code;
              const errorMessage = error.message;
              // ..

              alert(errorMessage)
            });
```

[image: here is a sample GUI design, if I clicked verify the email and password would be accepted because these credentials are not into the database using the current code I have. However, I do not want them to be added to the database. I want the verify button to check if the email is already in use and the password meets the parameters then display an alert saying so.]

here is a sample GUI design, if I clicked verify the email and password would be accepted because these credentials are not into the database using the current code I have. However, I do not want them to be added to the database. I want the verify button to check if the email is already in use and the password meets the parameters then display an alert saying so

Comment: Can you just confirm why you don't want to add credentials into database? Meanwhile have a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56901551/18265570) which helps fins existing email

Comment: Yes @RoopaM the reason is because the user will be subscribing to a paid service. I do not want to add the account to the database until they are subscribed. Do you have any other methods for this?

Comment: Can you try not resolving promise as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62012926/18265570)?

Comment: @RoopaM the first link you said worked!! Do you know how to create a custom error from firebase. When they display an error like "Firebase: auth error" etc... How would I write an alert, if (error == "Firebase: auth error") { alert("Email already in use") } ???

Comment: I shared my solution below, can you have a look at it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to verify email if it already exists without saving data into database, you can use [fetchSignInMethodsForEmail](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth.html#fetchsigninmethodsforemail) method. To display custom error messages you can use `Try` and `catch` block as suggested in this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/errors).

For Example:

```
.catch((error) => {
    if (error.code == "Firebase: auth error") {
        alert("The email address is already in use");
    }
```

To display detailed useful error messages use [functions.https.HttpsError](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors).

For more information have a look at these [thread1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70996401/18265570) &[thread2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56113778/18265570).